# When should I use a trait as a type in rust?

Tags: rust, traits

I recently started learning rust and was watching a video about traits and I learned traits were also valid types if dynamically dispatched. What is the point of having a variable with a trait as a type if it has the costs of

1. Must be heap allocated instead of stack allocated
2. Has an expensive initialization cost

```rs
struct Animal;

trait Roars {
    fn roar(&self);
}

//implement trait roar
impl Roars for Animal {
    fn roar(&self) {
        println!("roarrrrrr")
    }
}

//implement a method rawr
impl Animal {
    fn rawr(&self) {
        println!("rawrrrrrrrrr")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let lion: Box<dyn Roars> = Box::new(Animal);
    let cheeta: Animal = Animal;
    lion.roar();
    cheeta.rawr()
}

>>>roarrrrrr
>>>rawrrrrrrrrr
```

I tried looking all over google for when this pattern would be a good idea but I couldn't find anything all I know is that it **is possible** but it comes at a bit of a cost when it comes to code performance so when should i use this pattern?

Comment: This question seems quite subjective, so it might not be a good fit for stackoverflow. There are quite a few different reasons why one would choose to use dynamic dispatch, especially if it's a question of compromises in terms of performance penalties. I could encourage you to benchmark possible solutions depending on your use case. Typically, in your example, there is no good reason to use a Box as the concrete type is known. On the other hand, if you wanted to create a collection of arbitrary heterogenous animals, it would make sense to ponder using dyn, as opposed for example to enums.

Comment: "1. Must be heap allocated instead of stack allocated" that's [not always necessary](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c95dfa7d1f42a68a91d11f9b3c61fd31)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few places where this pattern is required:

- You have a container (e.g. `Vec`) whose items need to be heterogeneous, but must have a minimum of functionality to be useful in the container.  The canonical examples in software development tend to be a heterogeneous set of callback functions (expressed `Box<dyn Fn>` in Rust) or a heterogeneous set of GUI widgets, for example.  (What use is a container that can only hold one kind of widget?)
- You are writing a trait with a method that needs to return a type implementing some trait, but where the actual type cannot be named, which rules out the use of associated types.  You often see this with async methods on traits, which cannot yet exist as "async" (or return `impl Future`) until [TAIT](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2515-type_alias_impl_trait.html) is stabilized.  Until then, those trait methods need to return `Box<dyn Future>`.

There are other places where this pattern can simplify the code substantially.  Erasing types with `dyn` can often eliminate generic type parameters, and sometimes simplifying the code is worth the rather minor runtime cost of an additional heap allocation, vtable lookup, and indirection to the data.